# Does "Chapeau l’artiste" mean hats off to the artist?

Tags: expressions

Here is the context, but strangely I couldn't find another reference to the phrase.

> Chapeau l’artiste ! Ou plutôt les artistes pour The Artist. Le film, le réalisateur Michel Hazanavicius et l’acteur Jean Dujardin entrent dans la légende et la France avec, puisque la patrie des frères Lumière est le premier pays non anglo-saxon à remporter l’Oscar du meilleur film.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Chapeau l'artiste

is derived from the expression

> [**chapeau bas**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chapeau_bas) \ʃa.po bɑ\
>
> > *Avec un profond respect.*

This means you are showing respect to someone. The use of the word *"artiste"* doesn't have to be literal.

You are right, you can translate it by **[hats off to](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hats_off)**.

---

"[**Les frères Lumière**](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auguste_et_Louis_Lumi%C3%A8re)" are [The Lumière brothers, Auguste Marie Louis Nicolas and Louis Jean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auguste_and_Louis_Lumi%C3%A8re).

Answer (score 0):

I can also means a "Farewell" to the said "artist". You might come across this when someone public (usually with some artistic background) passes away.

Comment: Not in this context.